# How can I extend expiry time of Knox-Token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-knox

I haven't changed the settings of `Knox` in my Django app. The default expiry time is 10hours, how can I change this that it won't expiry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TOKEN_TTL**

```
    REST_KNOX = {
       'TOKEN_TTL': timedelta(hours=10),  # default time 10h
    }
```

> just do

```
    REST_KNOX = {
       'TOKEN_TTL': None,  # will create tokens that never expire
    }
```

> [check the documentation](https://james1345.github.io/django-rest-knox/settings/)

Answer (score 1):

Change the `TOKEN_TTL` item on `REST_KNOX`.
Based on docs.
`TOKEN_TTL`
This is how long a token can exist before it expires. Expired tokens are automatically removed from the system.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
REST_KNOX = {
  'SECURE_HASH_ALGORITHM': 'cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes.SHA512',
  'AUTH_TOKEN_CHARACTER_LENGTH': 64,
  'TOKEN_TTL': timedelta(hours=10),  # default time 10h
  'USER_SERIALIZER': 'knox.serializers.UserSerializer',
  'TOKEN_LIMIT_PER_USER': None,
  'AUTO_REFRESH': False,
  'EXPIRY_DATETIME_FORMAT': api_settings.DATETME_FORMAT,
}
```

Look at [docs](https://james1345.github.io/django-rest-knox/settings/) for more info.

Comment: I have gone through docs, but couldn't find the answer. A token mustn't expire

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I have found the answer. "TOKEN_TTL": None for an unexpiry token. Thanks, all